# Create multiple files within (sub)directory

Tags: bash, file, terminal, touch, brace-expansion

How can I create multiple files within the same directory/sub directory using one command in the terminal?

I know its possible with

```
touch ./path/to/the/directory/file1.txt  ./path/to/the/directory/file2.txt
```

but looking to see if I can skip entering the fullpath for every file.

I thought `touch ./path/to/the/directory/{file1.txt file2.txt}` would do the trick, but seems no.

Comment: `touch ./path/to/the/directory/{file1.txt,file2.txt}` or with a range: `touch ./path/to/the/directory/file{1..5}.txt`

Comment: Of course, that bluddy comma! Thank you :)

Comment: @Itdev : Don't forget that `touch` does not only create the file, if it does not exist, it also changes its timestamp, if it already exists. Depending on what you want to achieve, this may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Try this: `touch path/to/the/directory/file{1..4}{a,c,e}.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create multiple files within the same directory/sub-directory using one command in the terminal.

we can use `touch` command and `{}` wildcard to create multiple files in a single command. Here's an example command,

- An example command that does exactly what you want:

  ```
  touch ./path/to/the/directory/file{1..3}.txt
  ```

  This command creates `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` files inside the sub-directory.
- Creating multiple files having completely different names:

  ```
  touch ./path/to/the/directory/{readme,utils}.txt
  ```

  This command creates `readme.txt`, `utils.txt` files inside the sub-directory.
- Creating multiple files having different file extensions:

  ```
  touch ./path/to/the/directory/{index.html,style.css}
  ```

  This command creates `index.html`, `style.css` files inside the sub-directory.

**PS**: Above commands are using `brace expansion`. A brace expansion is contained between a pair of braces “{}”. It can be a list of comma-separated items or a range specifier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not finded better way then

`for i in file1.sh file2.sh file3.sh; do touch directory/$i; done`